# Callback with 3 parameters

Tags: java, callback

In modern Java, using a callback (a.k.a. function reference a.k.a. function pointer) with up to two parameters is pleasantly easy and straightforward. Example:

```
class a {
  public static Object plus(Object a, Object b) {
    return (Double) a + (Double) b;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BiFunction<Object, Object, Object> f = a::plus;
    System.out.println(f.apply(2.0, 3.0));
  }
}
```

(The parameters and return value can be typed, though they have to be object references, not primitives.)

The compiler directly knows about `java.util.function.BiFunction` and its smaller kin, as can be seen in the disassembly of the above `main`:

```
     0: invokedynamic #17,  0             // InvokeDynamic #0:apply:()Ljava/util/function/BiFunction;
     5: astore_1
     6: getstatic     #21                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
     9: aload_1
    10: ldc2_w        #27                 // double 2.0d
    13: invokestatic  #13                 // Method java/lang/Double.valueOf:(D)Ljava/lang/Double;
    16: ldc2_w        #29                 // double 3.0d
    19: invokestatic  #13                 // Method java/lang/Double.valueOf:(D)Ljava/lang/Double;
    22: invokeinterface #31,  3           // InterfaceMethod java/util/function/BiFunction.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    27: invokevirtual #36                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    30: return
```

There is, however, no `java.util.function.TriFunction`.

How do you set up a callback with three parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create your own `TriFunction` functional interface. Let's keep it simple and omit all the default methods for now:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
interface TriFunction<T, U, V, R> {

    R apply(T t, U u, V v);
}
```

The annotation is optional, but it will cause a compiler error if you add another non-default method.

Answer (score 1):

From a functional programing perspective you solve this with currying. Meaning your function return another function. You can pass the Function to methods (or other functions).

Here is your example with currying:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class A {

    public static Function<Double, Function<Double, Function<Double, Double>>> plus = a -> b -> c -> a + b + c;
    public static Function<Double, Function<Double, Function<Double, Double>>> multiply = a -> b -> c -> a * b * c;

    public static double doMath(double a, double b, double c, Function<Double, Function<Double, Function<Double, Double>>> calc) {
        return calc.apply(a).apply(b).apply(c);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Plus:     " + doMath(2, 3, 4, plus));
        System.out.println("Multiply: " + doMath(2, 3, 4, multiply));
    }
}
```